# How can i solve the integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

How can i solve the integral equation $$z(t) =\int_0^t z(q)(1-(t-q))\,dq+C?$$

Solving for the function $z$.

I have access to Mathematica.

Comment: In general, how to integrate any function $z(T)$, or do you have a particular $z(T)$ in mind?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The function i have in mind is the function i described in the text.

Comment: So you want to solve $z[T]=\int_0^T z(t)(1-(T-t))\,dt$ solving for $z$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes indeed :), its for modeling disease

Comment: If you want a $z(t)$ continuous at $t = 0$, then $z(0)$ has to be $0$ by your integral equation. Do you mean something like $z(T) = z(0) + \int_0^T z(t)(1-(T-t))dt$ instead? If you differentiate your integral for $T$ using Leibniz rule twice, you will obtain an ordinary $2^{nd}$ degree ODE with constant coefficient.

Comment: Exactly!! z(T)=z(0)+∫ T 0 z(t)(1−(T−t))dt

Answer (score 2):

Letting $w(T)=\int_0^T z(t)\,dt$, we see that $$w'(T)=z(T)=\int_0^T z(t)(1-(T-t))\,dt =  (1-T)w(T) + \int_0^T tz(t)\,dt$$

Differentiating again, we get:
$$w''(T) =  (1-T)w'(T) - w(T) + Tw'(T) =w'(T)-w(T) $$

$$w''(T) = w'(T) -w(T)$$

That's a pretty standard homogenous differential equation, with two initial conditions, $w(0)=0$ an $w'(0)=z(0)$ fixed by your condition.

Essentially, this means that $$w(T)=Ce^{T/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt 3 }2T\right)$$

Where $C$ is some constant determined by $w'(0)=z(0)$.

Comment: Please note Achille Hui's comment above that the only solution is $z(t)=0$ for all $t \geq0$, unless we change the equation.